# Hydrogen–deuterium exchange in 1,4-benzoquinone

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, isotope

#### Problem

> Find number of deuterium exchanges in the following compound.
>
> [image: 1,4-benzoquinone]

#### Solution

> 0 D-exchanges.

#### Question

I have been taught that hydrogen attached to the carbon which is directly or indirectly in conjugation with the ketone group will show deuterium exchange with $\ce{D2O}$ or $\ce{NaOD}$. Why does the solution claim there is no H/D exchange in *p*-quinone? Are the hydrogens attached to the double bonded carbons not considered in the conjugation?

Comment: Would highly appreciate if someone suggested a better tag. For now I just used a general tag.

Comment: Hydrogen attached to the carbon which *will be* in conjugation with electron withdrawing group after deprotonation, would be deprotonated. Is there one?

Comment: Still, I wouldn't be surprised if there *was* deuteration, if concentration of base was high enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a lot of energy to remove the hydrogen atoms from the $sp^2$ hybdridised carbon atoms (involved in double bonding). So there's not really any hydrogen atom which is readily available for removal and deuterium exchange.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But, let's say if there were that much energy, then nothing is stopping those hydrogens from being exchanged, right? They are in conjugation with the ketone group, so I dont think there would be any problem.

Comment: Yeah well if you provide a sufficient amount of energy, they can potentially participate in deuterium exchange. It's just that usually people don't consider that as a normal answer to problems like this.